# Do nested objects take up any more space in MongoDB than string keys?

Tags: mongodb

I'm looking to store pre-aggregated report data, grouped by day, in a document. I've got two options:

#### Option 1: flat-ish schema

For each day within `timeOnSite`, use a `yymmdd` key. All of these keys would be direct children of `timeOnSite`, so each key path will be `timeOnSite.yymmdd`.

```
{
  "timeOnSite": {
    "150421": 25,
    "150418": 42
  }
}
```

#### Option 2: nested schema

The nested key paths will now look like this: `timeOnSite.yy.mm.dd`.

```
{
  "timeOnSite": {
    "15": {
      "04": {
        "21": 25,
        "18": 42
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

I have very little preference on how the data is stored. I care about:

1. Fast queries
2. Using the smallest amount of storage space possible

Anyone know whether either of the above approaches is better? Many thanks.

---

**Update:** to address the question "what kind of queries will I run", it could be any of the following:

- Get the total time on site in the last 30 days: use a `$project` in the aggregation pipeline to `$add` up the total time on site. A further `$match` would be applied after this step for filtering.
- Detect if customers spent any time on site in the last 30 days, detected by the presence of a value in any of the above keys. This would be a big list of `$or` queries, each looking for the existence of a different key.

Comment: option 2 will take up more space and serialisation time due to the level of nesting

Comment: There is little one can do to speed up queries w/o knowledge of actual queries that will be performed on the data. There are a number of scenarios  for which both of your options will work crucially slow. How are you going to query date ranges for instance?

Comment: Have updated to address your question - thanks

Comment: @lig do you have any ideas on this? Thanks

Comment: "This would be a big list of $or queries, each looking for the existence of a different key." Just don't:) Each $or is exactly another separate complete query. That is exactly the reason of my first question. You should not store data in the keys as you do for dates. With wiredtiger backend it is not necessary to care of data repetition in keys as it will be addressed by WT compression. Just do somth like [{tos: "150421", count: 50}, {tos: "150419", count: 20}, {tos: "150522", count: 42}]. In this case you will be able to create index on "tos" and speed up a bunch of queries at least.